# Most pythonic way to get a range with a radius, and filter out too big or too small entries

Tags: python

I have implemented this algorithm:

```
def get_hot_pages(self, radius = 2):
    if self.page == None or self.max_pages == None: return []
    hot_pages = []
    for page in xrange(self.page - radius, self.page + radius + 1):
        if page < 0 or page >= self.max_pages : continue
        hot_pages.append(page)
    return hot_pages
```

But something tells me this can be implemented better. Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual "trick" is to use `max()` and `min()` in order to set the minimum and maximum page numbers:

```
def get_hot_pages(self, radius = 2):
    if self.page is None or self.max_pages is None: return []
    return range(max(self.page-radius, 0), min(self.page+radius+1, self.max_pages))
```

The main advantages of this approach are:

- People who know this standard procedure understand immediately what the code does (only one line to read). There is no need to read a whole loop block (which contains a filter test) in order to understand that some pages can be out of bound.
- This is efficient: there is no test inside a loop that runs at every iteration and filters out incorrect page numbers. It is generally good to keep an eye on efficiency (even if it does not matter here, it may matter in other situations): it often happens that a solution be *at the same time* simple, legible and quite efficient (i.e., looking for efficiency can actually make the code more legible, because it forces one to isolate the essence of the problem at hand).

Comment: +1, this is a better way of doing it. However, you might want to make it return a generator, rather than a list, and split out the `max()` and `min()` calls into local variables to make the function more readable.

Comment: [An example of what I mean.](http://ideone.com/xX1UCN) - I can't decide whether in 2.x, it would be better to return `[]` or `iter([])`. The first is the simplest, the latter consistency with the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else, a really simple improvement is to not produce a list, but make it a generator instead, which makes the function lazy (and nicer to read):

```
def get_hot_pages(self, radius=2):
    if self.page is None or self.max_pages is None: 
        return
    for page in xrange(self.page - radius, self.page + radius + 1):
        if 0 <= page < self.max_pages: 
            yield page
```

We can also reverse the logic in the loop, to remove the `continue`, and use Pythons better syntax for multiple comparisons on a single value, to reduce the size of the check. This all makes it more readable and efficient.

Also note the change of `x == None` to `x is None`, which is generally considered a little more readable (this works as all instances of `None` are the same, so checking by identity is fine). Instead of the `or`, we could also do `None in {self.page, self.max_pages}` -  although for only two items, I would say the `or` is clearer.

I also made a few changes in whitespace to conform to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves).

Comment: Good remarks, but there is really no need to "correct" the range with a test: the range can be set correctly directly (for instance as in my answer). Performing a test in the loop is inefficient (the test is run for every page, and the loop runs even for incorrect pages), and maybe less legible (the `for` clause looks like `page` is really allowed to take the values from the specified range, until one parses the rest of the code). The philosophy I am putting forward here is: "do things right directly instead of correcting problems later".

Comment: @EOL You make a great point - I didn't think of doing it that way as I was thinking about modifying the original, you are right it's a better answer, +1 to yours.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was your downvote, but to whomever downvoted, while I accept it's not the optimal answer, it's definitely not wrong, and a downvote doesn't seem reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this:

```
hot_pages = []
for page in xrange(self.page - radius, self.page + radius + 1):
    if page < 0 or page >= self.max_pages : continue
    hot_pages.append(page)
```

to that:

```
hot_pages = filter( lambda k: k >= 0 and k < self.max_pages, xrange( self.page - radius, self.page + radius + 1 ) )
```

not a big deal though and a bit more difficult to read (at least in my opinion).

Comment: As with Lattyware's solution, there is no need for a test inside the loop, and it is inefficient to test each and every page (both those that can be included, and those that can't).

Comment: @EOL The question was not about efficiency but pythonic way. Or at least that's how I understood it.

Comment: @freakish: Its hard for me to understand, how converting the loop to a filter and lambda makes it more Pythonic.

Comment: @Abhijit 1 line instead of 4? As I said: not a big deal.

Comment: `1 line instead of 4?` I thought in Python `readability Counts` rather than `complex 1 liner counts`

Comment: You are right about efficiency not necessarily being an issue here; it can be an issue though, that's why I mentioned it. I would argue that this solution is unnecessarily complicated (going over an incorrect range, and then taking the time to correct incorrect values, as opposed to directly going through the correct range), and is therefore less Pythonic. "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: I don't want to argue what's more pythonic and what's not. It is a matter of style after all and different people will understand that differently. EOL, I agree that your solution is better ( although keep in mind that this might be just a snippet and the actual test might more complicated and in that scenario my solution is better ). Still I don't think my solution deservers -1.

Comment: I removed my -1. :) There would indeed be no point to argue about what's more pythonic. However, my experience is that situations where one feels compelled to do something "wrong" (here, iterate over too large a range) and then correct it (here, filter out wrong pages) can always be done right directly (here: iterate over the correct range). I consider looking for the simpler solution good programming practice:; it falls under a principle I hold that says that code should be reasonably optimized (i.e. made algorithmically efficient with little effort, by using the resources of the language).

Comment: PS: your `filter()` could be written more clearly with a list comprehension: `hot_pages = [page for page in xrange(self.page - radius, self.page + radius + 1) if page >= 0 and page < self.max_pages]`.

Comment: Efficiency was indeed a concern. As well as using a pythonic approach (in order to make this easy readable)